# How can identify Facebook post is already liked or not using Facebook graph API?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I used **Facebook Graph API**  for getting Feeds, I used below query :

> me/home?fields=full_picture,description,message,comments,likes,created_time,id,link,caption,name,from.fields(id,name,picture)

Now, How can i identify that Post is already Liked or not by current login user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the Latest Facebook Graph API... It works for me.